# git post-receive-email hooks.showrev pretty formatting?

Tags: git, formatting, hook

I'm trying to do this:

```
git show --format=format:"parents:%p%ncommit:%h%nauthor:%an%n%N%n%s%n%b" -C; echo
```

in my hooks.showrev in my post-receive-email script for git:

```
custom_showrev=$(git config hooks.showrev || git show --format=oneline --abbrev-commit -C %s; echo)
```

using the "standard" post-receive-email script. It just gives me the following error:

```
remote: /home/git/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email: line 631: parents:0937024: command not found
```

when I commit with git from the console. Line 631 has:

```
            eval $(printf "$custom_showrev" $onerev)
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Specifically, my question is, how do you use a custom format with the post-receive-email hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
eval $(printf "$custom_showrev" $onerev)
```

the printf tries to take the format string and insert $onerev at one of the % spots and then eval everything.

Simply replace the eval line with the line:

```
git show --format=format:"parents:%p%ncommit:%h%nauthor:%an%n%N%n%s%n%b" -C $onerev
```

and it will work.

Comment: Probably better to us %cn for commit author instead of %an (which I believe represents the person who started the branch)